# Pi zero W sudden permanently slow Wi-Fi cripples VNC/updating. Extensive troubleshooting

Tags: wifi, pi-zero-w

## Usage.

Thank you to anyone that tries to help, your efforts are really appreciated

I ssh into a pi zero W to send a wake-on-Lan signals to my main PC. I am far away and won’t be able to get at the Pi physically for months.

For three weeks the pi has worked flawlessly

However. suddenly the internet speeds and connection got so bad that I am unable to update the pi or use vnc to start my main pc 400 km away.

Fourtunately the PC was on at the moment so i can troubleshoot.

There is no problem with the Internet or router, since it works flawlessly on my main PC. Router is on a weekly reboot

## Tried

- Rebooting, have the Pi on a daily reboot
- Power saving mode off, made it possible to consistently get access to the pi, most ssh calls succeeds.
- Disable realvnc service, might have helped with above result
- Make router only provide internet on specific channels and 2.4 GHz, worsened the problem.

## Diagnostics

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Home"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: xxxx
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-39 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

ifconfig

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 149  bytes 21061 (20.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 149  bytes 21061 (20.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.245  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::fc2:df10:ce59:2209  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:f4:90:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 80580  bytes 22632305 (21.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18063  bytes 2396849 (2.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

dmesg(edited)

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.10.17+ (dom@buildbot) (arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 8.4.0-3ubuntu1) 8.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #1421 Thu May 27 13:58:02 BST 2021
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=720 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:A1:C5:B8 vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
[    0.000000] Kernel parameter elevator= does not have any effect anymore.
               Please use sysfs to set IO scheduler for individual devices.
[    3.304549] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1074: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = d7d14000 dma = 0x97d14000 len=9024
[    3.304591] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    3.304615] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    3.304813] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:457: FIQ on core 0
[    3.304836] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:458: FIQ ASM at c0652330 length 36
[    3.304874] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:497: MPHI regs_base at dc810000
[   19.816202] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 22 2019 01:59:28 version 7.45.98.94 (r723000 CY) FWID 01-3b33decd
[   30.222576] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   30.240283] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[20296.348850] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
[20296.348898] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_channel: chanspec failed (-110)
[20342.246005] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_run_escan: error (-110)
[20342.246053] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-110)
```

rfkill list

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```